# Formatting text in Microsoft Word

Tags: audio, microsoft-word

I have a transcript formatted in hanging indents. On the left is speaker identification and time stamps, and on the right, the text. I want to make all the speaker identifications and timestamps bold. It is easy to deal with the names by using find and replace, but how can the timestamps be set to bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Find and Replace, enter the search term "[^#:^#^#:^#^#]", click the "Find In" button, and select "Main Document" to select all of the time stamps at once (screenshot below). With all of them highlighted, you can just press Ctrl + B to add the bold formatting to them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]

**Find what**: `[! ]\[*\]*^t` (*Use wildcards* enabled)

**Replace with**: `^&` (*Font: Bold* set via *Format* button)

This will set both timestamps and speaker names to bold in one go.